# Prove that the Cauchy problem has a unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given ${x}\prime (t)=A(t).x(t)+b(t) $ where  $A(t), b(t)$ are continuous on $[a,b]$. Prove that the Cauchy problem has a unique solution.
i.e 
$$\begin{cases}
x\prime(t)&=A(t).x(t)+b(t)\\ x(t)&=x_{0}; \quad t_{0} \in (a,b)
\end{cases}$$
How to apply Picard-Linderlof method or another way here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $f(t,x)=A(t)x+b(t)$ you will find that there is a Lipschitz constant
$$
L=\max_{t\in[a,b]}\|A(t)\|
$$
which exists given that $A$ is a continuous function.